# Do docker volumes have to be hosted on the host machine?

Tags: docker

I've used the Docker Desktop to get a Laravel site running and it's been successful. What I'm not sure of is how things should work in a production environment.

I've chosen to use two existing images: redis:4.0-alpine and mariadb:10.4.11. The other two images I made: recognizerhd/nginx-remote-log:latest and recognizerhd/php-fpm:latest. The containers all connect to the same network. There are two volumes, one for the database, and another for the Laravel files that are mounted to the nginx and PHP containers.

I am currently signed up with OVH, and I've looked a little into DigitalOcean. Host, I guess, is mostly irrelevant unless they don't offer even the basic needs to get a docker setup running.

I've created an instance and added a volume. I've had to mount that volume on the instance in order to access it. Am I understanding correctly that this is only the server level and a volume here has nothing to do with the volumes that Docker uses?

Furthermore, do volumes always have to be hosted on a docker container? I guess what I was expecting was that hosting providers removed a lot of the setup and let you create networks, volumes, containers while they managed the infrastructure and billed you for the resources you used. I don't think I can increase the size of the storage on the instance itself, it's locked to 20G on the package I'm on, but I can increase the volume. Is this the benefit of using the hosting provider's volume is that it can be increased as I need it?

- Do volumes always have to be hosted on a docker container?
- Am I understanding correctly the hosting provider's volume has nothing to do with the volumes that Docker uses?
- Am I using docker appropriately? i.e. Am I doing anything outside of the norm that I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)  are a Docker-specific construct that, as you're doing, are used to represent (file) storage used by containers (!). Volumes are similar to [bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) but are distinct.

Docker volumes are a unit of distribution for files that are available to containers (only). The concept of volumes appears often and refers to block (file) storage generally and is commonly used to refer to "disks" used by VMs. These concepts while similar are not transferable (VMs<-->containers).

Docker volumes are inextricably (!) bound to the host machine on which they're created. Unlike container images that may be pushed to and pulled from registries to move them between machines, volumes are unable to escape their creating host.

When you deploy your Docker (Compose?) solution to any other host (including those on cloud providers such as Digital Ocean), you must recreate the volumes you need on any of those remote hosts.

I'm unaware of any mechanism that facilitates moving volumes between machines as you need but it's entirely reasonable to want this functionality.

In the case of your e.g. database volume, the process by which you created that for your local host, must be replicated to create that volume on the remote host where you wish to access it even though you will be able to `docker pull` the database container image.

To answer your questions (as I understand them):

- Volumes must be created on any Docker Engine (!) host where containers will be run that depend upon the volumes;
- Correct: the concept of volumes is broadly applicable but, a cloud provider's concept of a volume will likely refer to some block (file) storage available to be used by VMs (not containers directly);
- Your approach seems perfectly good. If you're not using Docker Compose, this may help in treating the containers and volumes as a unit (but Compose won't aid in moving solutions between hosts);

You are unable to use this but, by way of example, Kubernetes which is a popular complementary technology to Docker, includes a capability called [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) that provides functionality similar to what you're seeking.

Comment: Good to know my approach sounds good.

During my research, I had developed a composer file along side manual docker run commands so I could know what they were doing. 

The volumes being tied directly to the host, appart from the Kubernetes' persistent volumes, definitely cleared some things up. 

Thanks.